# Inject code on every page in a web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, right-click

I have some code to disable the mouse right click (yeah I know, don't shoot the messenger) Is there a way to include it on every page without manually adding it  to every page. Unfortunately the pages don't have included headers or footers. I was thinking maybe there was a way to do it via the global.asax?

Edit: to be clear, this is an ASP.NET WebForms project. There are no headers or footer that I can put the code into and master pages are not an option. There is also no common JavaScript file that is included on every page. I need some way to inject some JavaScript code into each page of the web application because I don't really want to have to go through each page and add it manually

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Your use cases aren't clear in this form...

Comment: Have you considered using a Masterpage?

Comment: Why cant you add it in index page?

Comment: Masterpages aren't an option unfortunately
I can add it to the index page but it also needs to go on all the other pages

Comment: Is it an ASP.NET WebForms or MVC application? How is it structured? Do you have a javascript file that you indclude in all your pages?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET WebForms project. Unfortunately there is no common JavaScript file that is included on every page

Comment: You can implement IHttpHandler to modify all responses but what a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeginRequest inside of the global.asax to achieve what you are asking:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('do something');</script>");
    }
```

Personally I would suggest refactoring the site to use masterpages or common js file, but I guess that's a business decision to work around it :)

Cheers

Comment: This does work but it doesn't make for very pretty HTML. I was hoping to find a solution that inserts the code in the <head> tags

Comment: @Crowcoder 's suggestion of using IHttpHandler is your alternative. This is why I think a refactor is a more practical approach.